# Экранирование тегов в html при выдаче по запросу

Tags: html

формирую маленький html на сервере и отдаю его пользователю, почему то появляется переход на новую на стороне клиента, хотя на сервере формируется без новой строки.
Пробовал экранировать теги (<) но что то на стороне клиента так и отображается <url;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            array[1].push({
                "main": "<url>http://stub.com</url>"
    });
    </script>
```

на стороне клиента

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            array[1].push({
                "main": "
                <url>http://stub.com</url>"
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте изменять код main с тегами, без них

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, что без тегов все нормально будет в одной строке, если опустить первый тег а последний оставить то на новой строке будет только </url>

Comment: Одинарные кавычки не помогают? Более не знаю

Comment: Что формируете, то и отдается, браузер не трогает html.

Comment: Так я прям сам прописываю html без пробелов, не имеет значения формируется или готовый скрипт читается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте кодировку исходного html-файла и вид переносов строки. Может стоит не LF (линукс), и не CR+LF (виндовс), а только CR (мак). При загрузке на сервер ftp-программа может менять эти переносы, если загрузка идет в текстовом режиме.